# Cannot install IDLE for Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, idle

I am trying to install IDLE 2.7 using terminal and software center, and I get the same mistake:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

idle-python2.7: Depends: python2.7-tk but it is a virtual package
```

I am using Ubuntu 14. Any ideas how to solve this issue? IDLE 3.4 is working fine, though I need 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install python-tk idle-python2.7 idle
```

Using aptitude instead of apt-get may offer some automatic solutions for removing conflicting packages.